# PHP - Multidimensional array epanded from variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array stored in `$members`

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
    ["index"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["routePartitionName"]=> string(20) "US-555-foop-GWRoutes" } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["index"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["routePartitionName"]=> string(27) "Cluster DN Presence Allowed" } 
[2]=> array(2) { 
    ["index"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["routePartitionName"]=> string(26) "Cluster DN Presence Denied" } 
}
```

I'm trying to embed this into another array during a foreach loop. However it seems to evaluate the `$members` variable as text.

```
$programTags[] = array(
    "name"=>"$cssname",
    "description"=>"$cssdescription",
    "members"=>"$members");
```

How can I expand the variable thus creating a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Remove the quotes from $members variable, it convert it into string.
$programTags[] = array(
    "name"=>"$cssname",
    "description"=>"$cssdescription",
    "members"=>$members);
```

Comment: Worked exactly like I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using nested `foreach`

```
foreach($members as $array)
{
    //$array is array variable .

     foreach($array as $values)
     {
        //your code here
     }
}
```

exapmple:

```
$member = array(3) { 
               [0]=> array(2) { 
                         ["index"]=> string(1) "1" 
                         ["routePartitionName"]=> string(20) "US-555-foop-GWRoutes" } 
               [1]=> array(2) { 
                         ["index"]=> string(1) "2" 
                         ["routePartitionName"]=> string(27) "Cluster DN Presence Allowed" } 
               [2]=> array(2) { 
                        ["index"]=> string(1) "3" 
                        ["routePartitionName"]=> string(26) "Cluster DN Presence Denied" } 
           }
```

applaying `foreach` then,

```
$array = array(2) { 
                         ["index"]=> string(1) "1" 
                         ["routePartitionName"]=> string(20) "US-555-foop-GWRoutes" 
          }
```